# Combine all materials that share the same color value

Tags: materials, objects

When creating my first model, somehow I created a new material for each part of the body. And then when I merged it all together I ended up having *many* different materials, all with slightly different names, but the same colors.

Is there a button or a script I can run that will:
-Identify all materials in object.
-see if any are identical in color (not name, they all have different names and extensions). 
-Delete duplicate-in-color materials
-Set all parts of the object that used the duplicate material to use the original material instead.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do the materials look like? Can we assume this Cycles with a single diffuse shader?

Comment: @JakeD yes. Cycles render and only one diffuse shader